# jquery: target div containing more than 2 words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to target a div that containing more than 2 words…and hide them.
e.g. a set of div's like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div>two words</div>
    <div>two words</div>
    <div>three words no</div>
    <div>two words</div>
    <div>two words</div>
    <div>three words no</div>
    <div>two words</div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle for code tests: http://jsfiddle.net/x9q8f/1/

Ideally I'm trying to target any `.wrap div` that contains more than 2 words, it may be 3, 4, 5 words etc etc, I'm just want to display the divs that contain 2…if this is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the text with word separators and count the number of parts

```
$('.wrap div').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()).split(/\W/).length > 2
}).hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CRp2g/)

Answer (score 2):

Use split function. Get all the divs, and check to see if

```
.innerHTML.split(' ').length >=2
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9q8f/2/)

Comment: nice solution, one problem though: http://jsfiddle.net/x9q8f/5/ when there are extra spaces in the div these aren't taken into account. As the content will come via CMS I have no control over spaces added by people, I just need to target 2 words (regardless of spaces) if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
var divs = $(".wrap div");
$.each(divs, function(key,val){
    if ($.trim($(val).text()).split(" ").length > 2) {
        $(val).hide();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x9q8f/7/)

Updated!

Comment: nice solution, one problem though: http://jsfiddle.net/x9q8f/6/ when there are extra spaces in the div these aren't taken into account. As the content will come via CMS I have no control over spaces added by people, I just need to target 2 words (regardless of spaces) if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.filter()` and `.split()`.

```
var $divsWithMoreThanTwoWords = $('div').filter(function(){
  return $.trim($(this).text()).split(' ') > 2;
});

$divsWithMoreThanTwoWords.addClass('wordy').hide();
```